# What is growth function and order where inner loop variable is multiplied by 2

Tags: big-o

I'm confused on what happens with the `*2` in the second loop. 
I understand that the first loop makes `n` iterations
the second loop increases by `*2` so I'm not sure how to determine how many iterations that would be. Like if it was `+2`, I believe we'd do `n/2` iterations for the second loop.

```
for (int count = 0; count < n; count ++)
{
    for (int count2 = 1; count2 < n; count2 = count2 * 2)
    {
        System.out.println(count, count2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we should assume this is homework unless you say otherwise?

Comment: It was a question on a test that I'm really angry about missing. Seemed really simple.

Comment: ok, you could try running the program with different values of `n` and see what's printed out. As a hint, the inner loop runs `1` time if `n=1..2`, `2` times if `n=3..4`, `3` times if `n` is upto `8`, `4` times if `n` is upto `16`, `5` times if `n` is upto `32`. What is this function that maps `2=>1`, `4=>2`, `8=>3` and so on? I'm writing up an answer also, but you might get it beforehand.

Comment: the inner loop doesn't depend on the outer loop, so you can handle them separately... it's really simple.

Comment: I was going to add this to my answer, but it doesn't really belong there. Re your remark "Like if it was +2, I believe we'd do n/2 iterations for the second loop." This is true. However as you may know the order is still the same, i.e. O(n^2/2) =  O(n^2), because multiplying by a constant makes no difference to the order.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath a lot of people don't get what the function is in the inner loop, especially under pressure in an exam or interview (I've seen physics / maths people not get this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you get the simpler case:

```
for (int count = 0; count < n; count ++)
{
    for (int count2 = 1; count2 < n; count2 ++)
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^
    {
        System.out.println(count, count2);
    }
}
```

here the outer loop runs `n` times, and the inner loop runs `n` times so we simply multiply `n` by `n` to get O(n<sup>2</sup>). (The fact that the inner loop in this code fragment only runs `n-1` times doesn't make any difference to the order.)

So the question is, in your example where we double `count2` each time, what is the function for the inner loop? Let's call the function for the running time of the inner loop `f(n)`. So our big-O will be O(n f(n)).

Let's look at the inner loop. It runs `1` time if `n=1..2`, `2` times if `n=3..4`, `3` times if `n` is upto `8`, `4` times if `n` is upto `16`, `5` times if `n` is upto `32`. What is this function that maps `2=>1`, `4=>2`, `8=>3` and so on?

What you should notice is that `2 = 2^1`, `4 = 2^2`, `8 = 2^3`, `16 = 2^4` and so on. What you want is the opposite to raising by a power of 2, and this is log to base 2 (but for big O the log doesn't matter).

So `f(n) = log(n)`, and we have **O(n log(n))**.

*Edit*: the easiest way to get a feel for what's going on is to simply run your program with different values of `n`. E.g. with `n=8` you get the output:

```
(0,1), (0,2), (0,4)
(1,1), (1,2), (1,4)
(2,1), (2,2), (2,4)
(3,1), (3,2), (3,4)
(4,1), (4,2), (4,4)
(5,1), (5,2), (5,4)
(6,1), (6,2), (6,4)
(7,1), (7,2), (7,4)
```

Number of iterations = `n log2(n) = 8 * 3 = 24`. This is an exact relationship where `n` is a power of `2`. In other cases, the relationship isn't exact. E.g. for `n=7` you get the same output (bar the last line), but the code is still O(n log(n)) because you can choose a constant `k=2`, say, such that the number of iterations of the inner loop is `<= k n log(n)`.

Comment: Oh!! I completely forgot about log! Thank you so much! Makes a lot of sense now!